# ERC-721 safeTransferFrom is overloaded?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, erc-721, function-override

According to ERC-721 interface the function safeTransferFrom seems to be overloaded:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public;
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) public;
```

Why so? Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 5):

The one without `_data` doesn't send any data when it calls the other contract. (It sends a zero-length byte sequence.)

The one with `_data` does.

Comment: This is incorrect, the other contract must implement the wallet interface, which has the 3-parameter function `onERC721Received(address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data)`. If you only pass two, the transaction will fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of my answer you think is "incorrect." Could you explain further? Perhaps there's something that could be clarified. (To be clear, I agree with the rest of your comment.)

Comment: "The one without _data doesn't send any data when it calls the other contract." - technically it should still pass data when it calls the other function, the data is just an empty string (see my answer below).

Comment: Ah, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ERC-721 draft standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md), take note of the code comments in the interface provided.

Specifically, for the `safeTransferFrom` function without the 4th parameter:

```
/// @dev This works identically to the other function with an extra data parameter,
///  except this function just sets data to ""
```

So your three-parameter function should do exactly the same as the four-parameter function, but pass `""` as the data.